# How to emphasis a row in listview?

Tags: android

I have a listview with many values. I want my first row to be highlighted always. i.e. It should have an orange color border. How can I implement it? Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change its style in the `getView()` method of your adapter depending on the `position` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requestFocus() on your listitems. So you get the firstChild from your listview and  call requestFocus() API.

Answer (score 0):

u can use Listview with Header

```
mListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```